# php preg match all, all the `p`

Tags: php, preg-match-all

```
<?php
$str= <<<ETO
<p>one
two</p>
<p>three</p>
ETO;
preg_match_all('/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/',$str,$r);
print_r($r);
?>
```

I am studying `preg_match_all`. I want get all the `p` from one article. but my code only get the second `p`. how to modify so that I can get the first `p`, either. Thanks.

Comment: You're studying wrongly.

Comment: @BoltClock, could you teach me more? Thanks.

Comment: It's just that regex is often the wrong tool to use for parsing HTML.

Comment: look into using a HTML parser: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the `/ims` flag at the end of your regex. Otherwise `.` will not match line breaks (as in your first paragraph). Actually `/s` would suffice, but I'm always using all three for simplicity.

Also, preg_match works for many simple cases. But if you are attempting any more complex extractions, then consider alternating to phpQuery or [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/) which allow for:

```
foreach (qp($html)->find("p") as $p)  { print $p->text(); }
```

Answer (score 2):

(.*?) is not matching newline characters. Try the /s modifier:

```
<?php
$str= <<<ETO
<p>one 
two</p>
<p>three</p>
ETO;
preg_match_all('/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/s',$str,$r);
print_r($r);
?>
```